# How can I save an integer value to Firebase in Flutter and retrieve this saved value?

Tags: flutter, firebase, authentication

I am making an application with Flutter and in this application I want to login with integer-value-password that I have saved in database instead of email-password login. I guess there is no such login form in Authentication. So where do I save this integer value?

As an example, a student will log into the system with their school number and password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write your backend API for this, for example with cloud functions that read/write from your database.